# Meaning of notation $\operatorname{ord}_Q(g)$ in "Algebraic Curves" by Fulton

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, notation, algebraic-curves

I didn't understand this notation in the chapter 7 page 93 of [Fulton's algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf):

[image]

What the author means by $\text{ord}_Q(g)$?

Maybe he would like to say $\text{ord}_Q(G) := \text{ord}_P(g)$?

I need help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your $X := Y$ is what "Define $X$ to be $Y$" means.

Comment: @jdc I know, my mistake. Thank you for the remark.

Comment: I didn't mean to correct you. What I means was that I think you are asking if Fulton is defining $\mathrm{ord}_Q(G)$ to be equal to  $\mathrm{ord}_Q(g)$, and if that is what you are asking, then, the answer is that indeed he is.

Comment: Saying that you need help is redundant, especially in titles. I edited the title to make it more descriptive.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday thank you

Answer (score 1):

Fulton denotes $\mbox{ord}_{P}(C)$ to be the order function on $k(C)$ defined by $\mathcal{O}_{P}(C)$. Where $C$ is an arbitrary curve and $P$ is a point on that curve. This is found on the first two paragraphs of **chapter 7, Resolution of Singularities, section 7.1, page 81**.

Hopefully this can give you some insight on how this applies to $\mbox{ord}_{Q}(G)$.